# how do i place a sequential count or index based on a column value in mulesoft data weave?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

i need to write a sequence/index in a column based on values in another column. **Please find sample below to explain my request :**
Here i need to generate index values in the customindex column based on the values in color column.. so basically if there are 4 rows with red in column, then it should index the rows as 1,2,3,4 and then when its 2 rows with blue as a value, it should again index from 1 -> 1,2.

Input data:

```
[
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": ""
  }
]
```

here is the transformation that i need help with:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var TM = flatten(payload map ((item, index) ->
[{
"Type":payload.type, //HEADER VALUES
"Color":"",
"Customindex":""
}]++
[{
"Type":payload.type,// LINE ITEM VALUES
"Color":payload.color,
"Customindex":index // need the index sequence to only count similar colors.. For ex : red start with 1,2,3 then for blue again 1,2 and so on
}]))
---
(((TM distinctBy $ ... filters and groupings
```

**Sample data with details (THIS IS THE EXPECTED OUTPUT):**
[image: sample table custom index is the expected column]

Comment: Provide a sample input and a corresponding output. From the SS I gather the output is CSV, if so then just provide the input data.

Comment: Dear @George , Please find sample input below. i basically want sequence numbering for lineitems only(not headers) with same color.

Comment: [
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
    },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": "",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": "",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": "",
    },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": "",
    },

  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": "",
    }
]

Comment: Ideally you should be editing the original post (I did it for you) as compared adding data in a comment where you have no formatting avalable to you.  Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, there are comments added inline:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv

var data = [
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Customindex": "",
    "Color": "Red"
  },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Red",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Blue",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "Header",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": ""
  },
  {
    "Type": "LineItem",
    "Color": "Yellow",
    "Customindex": ""
  }
]
filter ($.Type != "Header")

// Create a map that contains the value of color as the key and the current-index
// in the value.
var vs2idx = data.*Color distinctBy $ 
             reduce (e,acc={}) -> acc ++ {(e): 1}
             
// Set the header object to be used later on
var header = {Type: "Header",Color: "", Customindex: ""}

---
/*
 * The accumulator contain two fields:
 *  1. The env that contains the state that keeps the color counters
 *  2. The result that contains the rows with the Customindex value
 * This data structure keeps re-created for every single row--this is necessary
 * because data in dataweave are immutable--i.e. we can't make any in-place
 * updates.
 */
(data reduce (row,acc={env: vs2idx, result: []}) -> do {
    var r = acc.result + (row update {
        case s at .Customindex -> acc.env[row.Color]
    })
    var e = {(acc.env - row.Color), (row.Color): acc.env[row.Color]+1}
    ---
    {env: e, result: r}
}).result
// group by color
groupBy $.Color
// Get the values of the resulting object
pluck $
// Iterate over the values and inject the header
reduce (e,acc=[]) -> acc + header ++ e
```

Even though I am outputing the data in JSON they are easy to be transformed into CSV.

Here's the documentation of the features of DW I made use of:

1. [reduce](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-reduce)
2. [Local variables](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-variables#example_local_variable)
3. [Multi-value selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors)
4. [update operator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#update-operator)

EDIT: Update the expression to generate CSV, without changing the position of the index and injecting the header rows.

Comment: Dear @George, will it ignore the header rows ?

Comment: Yes I did not do the headers, its easy--what you need is a `groupBy` followed by a `pluck` that gets just the values, then just merge the values and add to them the headers.  I will let you try it and if you still have issues, I 'll edit my answer tomorrow and give you a CSV with the headers.  But please try to do it yourself ;)

Comment: Dear @George, not sure why but it is throwing errors for me : BTW Thanks a lot for your help so far. i really appreciate your expertise.

Comment: Is it the preview?  I assure you the code does run.  It is datasense that throws these false positives.

Comment: Unable to call: `reduce` with arguments: (`Array<{|Type: "Heade..., Customindex: ""|}>`, (row, acc) -> `?`).
 Reasons:
 - Missing required property: `env` required by `{env: Object | {| Ye...ult: Array<Nothing>}`. 
  |- From: reduce(items: `Array<T>`, callback: (item: `T`, accumulator: `T`) -> `T`) -> `T | Null`  
   2748| fun reduce <T>(@StreamCapable items: Array<T>, callback: (item: T, accumulator: T) -> T ): T | Null = native("system::ArrayReduceFunctionValue")
                                                                                               ^
 - 
and so on.

Comment: ... and again is it the editor that shows the error?  Did you try to run the preview?  Did you run the server?  I get the same error and it is a false positive.

Comment: yes it did work amazingly. and i did replicate your logic to my actual payload. The only 1 issue i am facing is that the index numbers show up in the end. and not under the column name. In real payload, the column is 7th in order.. but after transformation it moves to the end and becomes the last column(26th)

Comment: I see, why don't you ask another question since this is different from your original question above--either myself or someone else will answer it.  I believe if I rewrite the code to make use the `update` operator it should be preserve the ordering.  I 'll do it tomorrow for you, either here or provide watch for answers in the new question you ask.

Comment: thanks. And sure, let me post a new question. Just so you know the original payload is quite huge and complex and thats why i used this sample - so it will be easy to understand and solution. Although the customer index column was last in the example i was expecting it to work as an update so the same code will work for all similar scenarios in all orders.

Comment: As I promised I completed the code to reflect the CSV output and the injected Header rows.  I also make use of the `update` operator so that the position of the index stays unchanged.